# Difference between two nanosecond chrono::time_points, but in seconds?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I have a timestamp (nanoseconds since epoch):

```
uint64_t ts = .....;
```

and I'd like to check whether it is more than 5 seconds older than the current system time.

So I need to convert the timestamp to, a `time_point`? and then subtract this from the current time (in nanoseconds), checking whether its value is greater than `chrono::duration::seconds(5)`?

Got this so far:

```
const std::chrono::time_point tstp(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(rawNanos));
const std::chrono::time_point now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

const bool old = now - tstp > std::chrono::seconds(5);
```

but struggling because of the constructor type for time_point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use `high_resolution_clock` for this.  On some platforms `high_resolution_clock` counts time since the computer was booted up, not time since the Unix epoch.

Although not specified by the standard, the de facto standard is that on all platforms, `system_clock` counts time since the Unix epoch.

I find it handy to first declare a templated type alias that is a `time_point` based on `system_clock`, templated on `duration`.  This makes it easy to create a `time_point` of any precision that counts time since the Unix epoch:

```
template <class D>
using sys_time = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, D>;
```

Given that:

```
uint64_t ts = 1235;
using namespace std::chrono;
const bool old =  system_clock::now() >
                      sys_time<nanoseconds>{nanoseconds{ts}} + seconds{5};
```

In C++14 you'll be able to write:

```
const bool old =  system_clock::now() >
                      sys_time<nanoseconds>{nanoseconds{ts}} + 5s;
```